# zend tool is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I've installed ZendStudio 7.2 it creates project normally with no error but when i try to add action(s) in it, it says project profile does not exist. and the error log is as follow:

```
executing zf create action showLatest index-action-included
                          An Error Has Occurred                         
 A project profile was not found.                                       

Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.10.2
Details for action "Create" and provider "Action"
  Action
    zf create action name controller-name[=Index] view-included[=1] module


Failed loading ./ZendDebugger.so:  (null)
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/bcmath.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/bz2.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/calendar.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/ctype.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/curl.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/exif.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/fileinfo.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/ftp.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/gd.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/imagick.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/json.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/ldap.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/mbstring.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/mcrypt.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/memcache.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/mhash.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/mime_magic.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/mssql.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/mysql.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/mysqli.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/pcntl.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/pgsql.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/posix.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/shmop.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/soap.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/sockets.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/sqlite.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/sysvmsg.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/sysvsem.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/sysvshm.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/tidy.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/tokenizer.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/wddx.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/xmlreader.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/xmlrpc.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/xsl.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/zip.so' - (null) in Unknown on line 0
```

please help me to configure latest ZendTool with ZendStudio 7.2 or how can i get rid of this.
i am runin ZS 7.2 on my mac os x 10.5.8

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the folder named Zend inside library in the file downloaded from framework.zend.com
Copy zf.php and zf.sh from bin directory to /usr/bin
Rename zf.sh to zf

open the terminal and test your installation by type zf and hit enter

http://qersh.com/blog/2010/08/05/how-to-install-zend-tools-1-10-on-ubuntu-10-04/